# Sequential scans instead of index with a PostgreSQL conditional index

Tags: postgresql, index, btree

I have the following PostgreSQL table, in it I store millions of rows.

I'm effectively trying to use it as a work queue, large lumps of JSON go in (`status=queued`) and get processed (`status=processed`).

```
\d item_uploads;
                                           Table "public.item_uploads"
     Column      |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                  Default                  
-----------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------
 id              | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('item_uploads_id_seq'::regclass)
 user_id         | integer                     |           |          | 
 last_timestamp  | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
 input           | text                        |           |          | 
 status          | character varying           |           |          | 'queued'::character varying

Indexes:
    "item_uploads_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_item_uploads_on_user_id_and_last_timestamp_and_id" btree (user_id, last_timestamp, id) WHERE status::text = 'queued'::text
```

For most of the time all but a few of the rows in the table will be `status=processed`.

I regularly run the query:

```
SELECT 1 AS one 
FROM   "item_uploads" 
WHERE  "item_uploads"."user_id" = 242 
       AND "item_uploads"."status" = 'queued'
```

What I'm noticing is that occasionally (often after an `ANALZYE`) Postgres will flip to a sequential scan.

My hope in using this conditional index was that it would always hit the index when I search for queued. Is this an unreasonable expectation? Obviously with the millions of non-"queued" rows what should be a cheap query becomes very expensive.

Comment: Can you capture an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of this query when the database gets into the sequential scanning mood?  Are there only two possible `status` values, or are there others?  Work-queue tables with partial indexes need to be vacuumed much more aggressively than regular tables do, do you have custom autovac parameters set up for this?  What version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: Is there a particular reason, the index is on `(user_id, last_timestamp, id)` and not just `(user_id)`? Or `(user_id, id, last_timestamp)`?

Comment: @jjanes - so I did, thanks! I should have made clear - Unfortunately this only crops up occasionally and each time it has I haven't got there in time to run an EXPLAIN ANALYZE. I have turned on auto EXPLAIN (which is why I know it's doing a seq scan). There are 2 other statuses. We do not delete rows from this table (hence the size) which for me discounts vacuum. We have no custom autovac - all default AWS RDS setup. Postgres 9.6.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). If you can generate both plans (the seq scan plan and the index scan) even better

Comment: I think you'll be helped out after reading https://jobs.zalando.com/tech/blog/analyzing-extreme-distributions-in-postgresql/ (Disclosure: written by a close colleague, on our company blog site)